# Need help wtih Facebook Share button

Tags: facebook

I have just put a facebook share button on a new site www.thaiaupair.com and when I click "share", facebook only shows a 'white' image on.

I've tried putting some og property on as below:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http//www.thaiaupair.com" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Thaiaupair.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.thaiaupair.com/Image/Slider0.jpg" />
```

The picture appears on the share preview but..
1.Doesn't appear on the 'shared' content
2.Nothing (no picture or link) is shown on the news feed either, only on my personal timeline.

I also checked at Facebook Debugger page. It still says that I need to provide 'og:url' and 'og:title', I'm so confused.

Please help. I have tried and tried but it's not working for me.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you currently have in the source code of your page:

```
<meta property=”og:url” content=”http://www.thaiaupair.com” />
<meta property=”og:title” content=”Thaiaupair.com” />
```

You need to use `"` as delimiter characters around HTML attribute values¹, not `”`.

[Validatiing your HTML code](http://validator.w3.org/) could have already told you that btw.

---

¹ Or single quotes, `'` – but in any way not “typographical” quotation marks.